# Heroku routing error rails css/javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am fairly new with rails and ruby and heroku, and am trying to deploy an app. The deployment works, but when i try to visit the site, none of the css, or JavaScript is loading. In the log it says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
```

I have tried adding `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` to my gemfile, doing assets:precompile, and a lot else, but yet the images and css still won't load. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ruby 2.0.0**
**rails 4.0.0**

Comment: What does the Heroku log say? (Type "heroku log" on the terminal), also write the entire error log.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an asset pipeline issue.  Have a look at the Heroku information for the rails asset pipeline:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

More than likely you'll have to precompile assets locally.

```
 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then just push to git and Heroku.